# Fonts inconsistent in table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, fonts

I am using a simple table object in SSRS that uses the default format of Arial 10.  It shows correctly in design mode, but when I execute the report, there are different fonts in different columns.  Notice in samples below, during report execution, columns 1,2 and 5 are different than columns 3,5.  Can someone explain this or point me in the right direction to get consistent output?  Thanks!

Design Mode

[image: Design Mode]

Executed Report

[image: Executed Report]

Answer (score 0):

Did you make any changes in the format?

if so, you have to clear cache by deleting the
file "reoprtName.rdl.data" in the project folder,

or rebuild the report.

[image]